# (Thread 1: Fatal error) How to make UIButton stop working if no data is retrieved from firebase

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app that asks users questions with 4 users that they are following being the answers at all times, then sending a notification to the user that is selected:

[Example image of app page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8RTA.png)

My problem is that if a user is following less than 4 people I receive an error that reads "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" - I have tried to add this:

```
                self.currIds.append(thisUserKey)
                if namesRemaining == 0 {
                    self.currNames = names
                    self.optionA.isEnabled = false
                    self.optionB.isEnabled = false
                    self.optionC.isEnabled = false
                    self.optionD.isEnabled = false
```

in order to make the button stop working if no users are loaded but it doesn't work. How can i make the button stop working and read "add more friends"

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var optionA: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionC: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionD: UIButton!

var user: UserModel?
var ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()
var currNames: [String] = []
var currIds: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getFourRandomNodesAndPrintUserName()
}


@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 1 {
        print(currNames[0])
        print(currIds[0])
    } else if sender.tag == 2 {
        print(currNames[1])
        print(currIds[1])
    } else if sender.tag == 3 {
        print(currNames[2])
        print(currIds[2])
    } else if sender.tag == 4 {
        print(currNames[3])
        print(currIds[3])
    }

    loadNewQuestion()
}

func getFourRandomNodesAndPrintUserName() {

    self.currNames = []
    self.currIds = []

    var myKeyArray = [String]()

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let ref = self.ref.child("following").child(uid)

    //retreives all nodes in the user_keys node
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.children.allObjects)
        for child in snapshot.children { //build the array of keys
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            myKeyArray.append(key)
        }

        var randomKeyArray = [String]()

        let numFollowers = min(4, myKeyArray.count)
        for _ in 0..<numFollowers { //will iterate four times
            let count = myKeyArray.count //get the number of elements
            let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<count) //get a random index for the array
            let randomUserKey = myKeyArray[randomInt]
            randomKeyArray.append(randomUserKey)
            myKeyArray.remove(at: randomInt) //remove that object so it's not selected again
        }

        let numberOfKeys = randomKeyArray.count

        var namesRemaining = numberOfKeys
        var names = [String]()
        var image = [String]()
        for i in 0..<numberOfKeys {
            let thisUserKey = randomKeyArray[i]
            let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(thisUserKey)
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as! String
                let pinionImage = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String
                // let image = same as above with "profileImageURL"

                print(name)
                print(pinionImage)
                namesRemaining -= 1
                names.append(name)
                image.append(pinionImage)
                // Another array for images

                self.currIds.append(thisUserKey)
                if namesRemaining == 0 {
                    self.currNames = names
                    self.optionA.isEnabled = false
                    self.optionB.isEnabled = false
                    self.optionC.isEnabled = false
                    self.optionD.isEnabled = false

                    self.optionA.setTitle(names[0], for: .normal)
                    self.optionB.setTitle(names[1], for: .normal)
                    self.optionC.setTitle(names[2], for: .normal)
                    self.optionD.setTitle(names[3], for: .normal)

                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I have also tried to edit the code so that if the user is following 3 or less people, the button should say "Follow more friends!" but if there is 4 or more following it should say the names of the users but the second part doesn't seem to work:

```
                self.currIds.append(thisUserKey)
                if namesRemaining <= 3 {

                    self.optionA.setTitle("Follow more friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionB.setTitle("Follow more friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionC.setTitle("Follow more friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionD.setTitle("Follow more friends!", for: .normal)

                } else if namesRemaining >= 4 {
                    self.currNames = names
                    self.optionA.setTitle(names[0], for: .normal)
                    self.optionB.setTitle(names[1], for: .normal)
                    self.optionC.setTitle(names[2], for: .normal)
                    self.optionD.setTitle(names[3], for: .normal)
                }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem seems to be with your `answerPressed`.  Either reduce the number of visible buttons on the screen, so the user can't select a button which has no name associated with it or change your `if-else` logic to check that there is an element available for the selected tag.  You logic could be reduced to `if sender.tag < currNames.count { print(currNames[sender.tag - 1]) }` or something simular

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Instead of removing the button, can i not just change the text on it to say "Follow more friends!" and stop it from being a button if they are following less than 3 people - then once they follow 4 or more people, make it update to the users names? I'm really new to this so would appreciate any help/explanation :)

Comment: Sure, then you something like `if sender.tag < currNames.count { print(currNames[sender.tag - 1]) }` in `answerPressed` to guard against the index out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

Create an outlet collection and hook all the buttons to it

```
@IBOutlet weak var allOptions: [UIButton]! // tags 0,1,2,3
```

And when you receive a new question detail

```
allOptions.forEach { $0.isHidden = $0.tag >= newAnswers.count }
```

And create a model instead of 2 arrays like

```
struct Root {
   let name:String  
   let id:Int 
}
```

Then

```
var newAnswers = [Root]()

@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) { 
    print(newAnswers[sender.tag].name)
    print(newAnswers[sender.tag].id)
}
```

> The button should not be shown if there is no info associated with it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would it not be possible to just keep the button as it is but just change the label to "add more friends" so that the user can just go and add more people instead of hiding the button?

Comment: yes you can but when you set that more label to it change it's tag to say 5 and handle it here  `} else if sender.tag == 5 {`